# R readr::read_fwf ignore characters using fwf_widths

Tags: r, fixed-width, readr, read.fwf

I would like to know if there is an easy way to skip characters using the read_fwf from the readr package in R.

For example, modifying one of the examples in the documentation

```
library(readr)
fwf_sample <- system.file("extdata/fwf-sample.txt", package = "readr")
read_fwf(fwf_sample, fwf_widths(c(2, -3,2, 3)))
```

throws the error:

```
Error: Begin offset (2) must be smaller than end offset (-1)
```

Using the base read.fwf function works just fine however:

```
read.fwf(fwf_sample, widths = c(2,-3,2,3))

#  V1 V2  V3
#1 12 67 890
#2 12 67 890
#3 12 67 890
#4 12 67 890
#5 12 67 890
```

Is there a way I can mimic this behaviour using `readr::read_fwf`?
(I am interested mostly for performance reason).

Comment: No error on my machine.b Using readr version 1.0.0. in R 3.3.1. On the other hand the negation is not honored and I get 4 columns.

Comment: I was on Ubuntu 64 bit with R 3.3.1 and readr 0.2.2.. I upgraded to 1.0.0 and I get the same issue now.. I think I'll stick to read.fwf for the moment...

Answer (score 1):

The help page suggests using `fwf_positions`:

```
> read_fwf(fwf_sample, fwf_positions(c(1, 5, 8), c(2, 7, 10),  col_names=paste0("V", 1:3)) )
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  V1 = col_character(),
  V2 = col_character(),
  V3 = col_character()
)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     V1    V2    V3
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1    Jo    Sm   ith
2    Ma    Ha   rtf
3    Ev    No   lan
```

Comment: Thanks, probably it's the only way.. though I don't like much this solution because it is extremely verbose...

Comment: You have an exceptionally strange notion of what qualifies for 'verbose' in computer programming.

Comment: I prefer skipping columns using negative numbers :) rather than having to build two vectors.. I must just be used to read.fwf.. I find it extremely intuitive :)

Comment: If you make x your intuitive column specification then these would be the values for the start and stop vectors in read_fwf: `tail(cumsum(c(abs(x), length(x)))[x>0], -1)`  .... 
[1]  7 10 14  `head(cumsum(c(1, abs(x)))[x > 0], -1)` ....
[1] 1 6 8