# Skip variables while reading in a fixed width text file in R using readr package

Tags: r, import, fixed-width, readr

I'm reading in some text files in R using the **readr** package because of the files fixed width but on some of the files I get the error that `cannot allocate vector of size...`. I'm assuming some files are too big but I actually don't really need all information in there, just a couple of variables.

This is what I'm using now to get the full file read in

```
mydata <- read.fwf(file=file.choose(), widths=c(29,42,42,29,30,25,10,3,10,10,10,10,10,10,20,10,10,10,10,10,10)
```

Those are 21 variables but I maybe only need 10 of them. Of course they are not positioned next to each other in the text file, but I do know their exact location in the file. Is there a way so that I can just read in the variables I want and ignore the others to save memory?

Thanks!

Comment: I just answered this question earlier today, at least the question expressed in the title. And `read.fwf` is not from pkg:readr. It's from pkg:utils. the reader function is named `read_fwf`. You would use negative number to skip over columns (as stated in the help file).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962983/r-readrread-fwf-ignore-characters-using-fwf-widths/38963466?s=2|2.7806#38963466